# Can I use useLocation() hook for global state instead of state management tool like redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

In my React app I set and retrieve some variables I use globally in the state of the useLocation() hook.

Example:

```
const { state } = useLocation();
const [groupId, setGroupId] = useState(state.data[0].groupId);
```

To get the groupId into state initially I would have done something like the following when fetching the data from the API in a different component:

```
const { state } = useLocation();
// fetch API Data
state.data = res.data;
```

I haven't seen this pattern used before so I'm concerned that it may be causing some consequences that I'm not aware of.

As my application grows there are more variables that I use in a number of different places. This is leading to prop drilling and large prop input lists.

Should I be storing any variables that I use a lot globally in the useLocation hook state like I've been doing or should these be in a global store such as redux?

Package versions:

- react: 17
- react-router-dom: 6.2.1

Comment: What's wrong with context?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with context hook.  Is there a reason this is preferable to redux-toolkit?

Comment: `state.data = res.data;` appears to be a mutation and should be avoided in React... probably also in general. It's rather unclear what you are actually asking about or for help with. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm asking 2 questions. 1. Is my current approach bad practice/wrong?  (Which you've essentially answered yes to).   2. Is this a problem that would ideally be solved by state management solution like redux-toolkit?

Comment: Context replaces Redux for primary purposes, it acts as a central data store for the application, which appears to be the functionality you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `location.state` ***is not*** for any global state. Route state is extremely transient/temporal, effectively existing *only* during the route transition from one page to another, and during the life of *that* component. `react-router-dom` maintains a global routing context, but this doesn't make it a global app state context.

`state.data = res.data;` appears to be a mutation and should be avoided in React... probably also in general.

You *could* hold the entire app state in route state, but the caveat here is that you'd need to:

1. Every component being navigating to/from would necessarily need to be aware of the "state" and cache a copy of it locally (*i.e. local component state*), use regular React state updates to update the local cache
2. Pass the "state" along with any routing actions, i.e. `navigate(newPath, { state })`, or `<Link to={newPath} state={state}>New Path</Link>`, etc it controls.

If you need global state and want to avoid props drilling then the React Context API is where you'd start.

See [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for more details.

Note that alone a React Context by itself ***is not*** a global state management system, it's merely a context container that allows you to pass props down to descendent components without the need to "props drill" them there.

React-redux and by extension Redux-Toolkit ***is***  global state management system. If you start with a Context and find you are holding a lot of state then you should consider integrating Redux to your app.

Comment: Thanks, this clears up a lot.  Is there a rule of thumb for determining whether I am "holding a lot of state" in a React Context solution?

Comment: @user2989759 I suppose when it starts to feel a little unwieldy. For example, if you are constructing a "state" object with N state variables ***and*** N state updaters, and it starts to feel messy. You *could* in the interim move to using the `useReducer` hook, but the "state" would still be a gigantic single object and you'd have a giant single reducer function. Moving to `react-redux` allows you to break the state down into single chunks of state and compose the state tree, *and* it has optimizations around state subsscribers.